# Can I listen to the Al-Quran while reading the translation?

Tags: quran, quran-translation, reading-quran

ASA. I love reading the Quran and understanding the meaning of it. However, my Arabic is not that good and it's difficult for me to understand the Quran. Say for example I'm trying to read the whole Quran multiple times in Ramadan, will it count if I am listening to the Quran and reading the translation at the same time or should I just recite it without knowing the meaning?

Comment: Ramadan is a time to reflect upon the Quran more than ever. You wouldn’t get the same reward reading it in English than in Arabic, however I’m sure you’ll get rewarded trying to obtain more knowledge on Islam + the teachings of the Quran. It’s encouraged to understand the Quran, specifically by reading it in your native tongue while also reading it in Arabic.

Comment: try to recite without knowing the meaning, or recite without knowing the meaning then after that read the translation (if you want). And Allah knows best.

Comment: I always study the meaning of the text before I learn to recite for I think that the message of the Quran is important. If in doubt, I use https://corpus.quran.com/ to know what it means, then listen on https//tanzil.org for correct recitation.